# What is wrong in the following snippet?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, code-snippets, object-oriented-analysis

I know it is a fairly basic violation, but what is it?

```
class xyz
{
    void function1()
    {
        cout<<"in class";
    }
};

int main()
{
    xyz s1 = new xyz(100);
    xyz s2 = s1;
    s2.function1();
    delete s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Something is wrong about the memory allocation using `new`. I believe but I can't seem to understand the fundamental behind it and the resolution.

Comment: You forget the star `*` in the type definition.

Comment: Does this compile

Comment: Where is the constructor that takes an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` returns a pointer (`xyz *`) to an object, not an object, so you should correct the type of `s1`:

```
xyz* s1=new xyz(100);
```

and to call the method through the pointer you should use operator `->`:

```
s1->function1();
```

which is the equivalent of dereferencing the pointer and calling the method on the object:

```
(*s1).function1();
```

Comment: "And you can" should be "And you have"

Comment: @Rakete1111, well, or you can call it using (*s1).function(); but yeah, rephrased to remove the possible ambiguity, thx :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign `T*` to `T` (pathological cases aside).

```
xyz * s1 = new xyz();
xyz * s2 = s1;
s2->function1();
delete s1;
return 0;
```

Better yet, don't use naked `new` and `delete` and use a smart pointer:

```
auto s1 = make_unique<xyz>();
xyz * s2 = s1.get(); // non-owning pointer
s2->function1();
// no explicit delete necessary
```

Comment: What are "pathological" cases?

Comment: A class `T` defining constructor from  `T*`. I've seen such in production code :(

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought about that :)

Comment: Where is the constructor that takes an integer

Comment: There isn't, I just copied the code with 100. Edited.

Comment: @Rakete1111 What about `void* ptr = new void*;` ;)

Comment: @BlackMoses Is this even legal? How should the compiler know the size of `void`?

Comment: Its `new`ing `void*`, not `void`

Comment: @Rakete1111 Basically you assign `void**` to `void*`, and since `void*` accepts any pointer, it's legal.